# MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10048)")

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I`m using to execute the following query

```
        connection= MySQLdb.connect(host=self.__host, user=self.__db_username, passwd=self.__db_passwd, db=self.__db, charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
        cursor= connection.cursor()
        sql= 'SELECT * FROM func1'
        cursor.execute(sql)
        data= cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        func1 = None

        if len(data)>0:
            func1s = []
            for item in data:
                func1= db_func1()
                #item = data[0]
                func1.id = item[0]
                func1.title = item[2]


                func1s.append(func1)
            return func1s
```

for the first time, it will be executed but after a sec it will  give me the error,and I`m using port 3306

thanks for any help

````
  File "C:\Users\elham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 164, in __init__    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10048)") ```
````

Comment: I recommend that you better format these codeblocks. Also, are you certain that the database is actually running?

Comment: yes, I`m sure, it works for a short time